# Change Margins on Kobo App

Tags: settings, kobo

I've recently installed the [Kobo App for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kobobooks.android) on a Galaxy Mega running Android 4.2.2.

The default margin width is way too big for my liking. Is there are way to change the margin setting?

I can see options to change font and colour settings. Are there any additional config files that give more control over this app's display style?

Comment: Possibly because your phone is so ridiculously large the app is giving it the screen layout it would have on 7in tablets. You should complain to the developer and ask them to fix it.

Comment: Many apps just upscale to the screen, with very mixed results. It's very apparent on a Nexus 7, worse on a 10. As Dan said, get on to the app developer, with a nice polite email it may only be a few tweaks (s)he needs to make and if he's a decent developer (s)he'll want to know!

Comment: Thanks Dan and RossC. I've notified Kobo and got a message back from their support team that my feature request has been received. Others with the same issue might consider doing likewise.